# react native: react-navigation crashes when navigating with headerRight

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

why doesn't this works ?:

```
headerRight: <Button title="Prout" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MenuCQ')}/>
```

When pressed, expo just crashes, with no error message at all. The onPress works on a button in my render method, so it *should* work in my headerRight, right ?

If not pushed, all the rest works, and the exact same button in my render method works well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your using react-navigation, you cannot access **'this'** inside screen **navigationOptions** as of v1.0.0-beta.11. But you will get navigation object of that screen which you can use to navigate as shown below

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerRight: <Button title="Prout" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MenuCQ')}/>
    }),
```

Comment: I'm getting this same error but using your code. I'm on react-navigation 1.5.1. If I change it to headerLeft, it works just fine.